# What should be done to useful posts posted by new users as answer but should be comments?

Tags: support, comments, answers

I am refering to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/394800/72576), which was posted as an answer, but should have been a comment to [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157471/72576). The user did not have enough rep(50) to post a comment, so he posted it as comment, mentioning his apathy.

Such posts would be deleted as **not an answer** and would result in the poster's frustration becoming someone else's frustration :D

Should such posts be copy pasted as comments or be deleted and lost forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag the question as "should be comment" Moderators can convert posts to comments.

Comment: I did not see that category, so I assume it meant "flag as 'other' with the custom reason  'should be comment'"?

Comment: Assuming it's a custom flag, I think that's not enough to solve the problem; This kind of answers/comments occur often, and it feels rude to flag them every time. Now I found out what to do, but it took a long time until I found that, and something in  "asked 9 month ago, viewed 22 times" on this question makes me think there are others that did not yet find it. Is it a realistic idea to propose it as a standard flag variant?